# Custom validation of a wrapped list throws UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030

Tags: java, spring, validation

I've been breaking my head about a custom validator to use on a list of objects.
The example is borrowed code, but is using a wrapper class, ValidList, to embed the actual list.
Now when I use an ootb annotation like Size(min=1) the validation works.
But if I use a custom annotation (don't look at the functionality, its for demonstration only here), I get a 500 error with the infamous  HV000030:

```
No validator could be found for constraint 'com.example.demo.validation.ListLength' validating type 'java.util.List<SomePojo>'. Check configuration for 'list'
```

when I call

```
$ curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST -d '[{"id":1,"token":"lalala"}]' http://localhost:8080/pojos
```

(I use the @Value from Lombok for getter/setter and immutability)

Anyone who knows whats wrong?

```
@RestController
public class SomeController {

    @PostMapping("/pojos")
    public ValidList<SomePojo> test(@Valid @RequestBody ValidList<SomePojo> pojos) {
        return pojos;
    }
}
```

```
@Value
public class ValidList<SomePojo> {
    @JsonValue
    @ListLength
    //@Size(min=1)
    private List<SomePojo> values;

    @JsonCreator
    public ValidList(SomePojo... items) {
        this.values = Arrays.asList(items);
    }
}
```

```
@Value
public class SomePojo {
    int id;
    String token;
}
```

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = ListValidator.class)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ListLength {

    String message() default "Not enough pojos";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

    @Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER})
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Documented
    @interface List {
        ListLength[] value();
    }
}
```

```
public class ListValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ListLength, List<SomePojo>> {

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(List<SomePojo> somePojos, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        return somePojos.size() > 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason of that exception is usage of `SomePojo` as generic parameter of `List` in `ListValidator` definition.
You should use wildcard for generic types in `ConstraintValidator` implementations.

Copied from javadoc:

> Implementations must comply to the following restriction:
>
> - `T` must resolve to a non parameterized type
> - or generic parameters of `T` must be unbounded wildcard types

So you should rewrite `ListValidator` as this:

```java
public class ListValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ListLength, List<?>> {

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(List<?> somePojos, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        return somePojos.size() > 1;
    }
}
```

For more info look at the [`ConstraintValidator` javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/ConstraintValidator.html) and [Bean validation documentation](https://beanvalidation.org/2.0/spec/#valueextractordefinition).

Comment: Yes this is doing the job. Should have known this one, but you helped me out. Thanks a lot Artem.